# ORA-00900: неверно предложение на языке SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Что я делаю не так?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Bank 
                AS TYPE ref_cursor IS REF cursor;

   FUNCTION CREATEDOC (
   p_mail_code       varchar2,  
   p_doc_no          varchar2 ,   
   p_doc_date        date,   
   p_document_type   varchar2,               
   p_flag_dk         varchar2,               
   p_okpo            varchar2,               
   p_customer        varchar2,               
   p_account_no      varchar2,              
   p_amount          number,                 
   p_mfo             varchar2,           
   p_ext_account     varchar2,            
   p_ext_customer    varchar2,      
   p_ext_okpo        varchar2,       
   p_description     varchar2,      
   p_currency_code   varchar2,       
   p_enrollment_date date,              
   p_country_code    varchar2,       
   p_add_params      varchar2,           
   p_key_buh         varchar2,                
   p_sign_buh        raw,                  
   p_key_dir         varchar2,                 
   p_sign_dir        raw,                   
   p_exception_code  out integer,
   p_error_code      out integer,
   p_error_str       out varchar2
 ) RETURN integer;
END Bank;
/
```

**Вывод:**
Предупреждения: ---> 
   W (1): Warning: выполнение завершено с предупреждением
          <---

0 запись(и) поддающаяся(иеся) действию

[Выполнено: 03.08.2017 17:06:09] [Выполнение: 65мс]

> [Ошибка] Строки сценария: 3-31 ---------------------
>    ORA-00900: неверно предложение на языке SQL
>    Строка сценария 5, строка инструкции 2, столбец 3

[Выполнено: 03.08.2017 17:06:09] [Выполнение: 0мс]

> [Ошибка] Строки сценария: 32-33 --------------------
>    ORA-00900: неверно предложение на языке SQL
>    Строка сценария 33, строка инструкции 1, столбец 0

[Выполнено: 03.08.2017 17:06:09] [Выполнение: 0мс]

Comment: Чего-то вы не договариваете. Я запустил ваш кусок кода на Oracle 11.2 - все отработало без ошибок...

Comment: А вы с помощью чего это выполняете ? Судя по всему ваш клиент отправляет в БД запросы, разбивая их по точкам с запятой. все стандартные утилиты рассчитанные на работу с ораклом понимают в каких случаях передавать надо весь блок целиком, до косой черты

Comment: @Mike, "Строка сценария 33" - говорит о том что весь блок был выполнен целиком - во всем блоке 33 строки...

Comment: @MaxU Но это не оракловые сообщения. Оракловые начинаются с ORA-. И есть отдельная ошибка в строке 5. И главное, есть 3 отдельных сообщения о выполнении блока. сначала успешно сознается пакет с единственным объявленным типом внутри, потом сыпяться ошибки на остаток текста по точкам с запятой. при равильной отправке в оракл должно быть одно единственное сообщение об успешном выполнении и все, а не 3 разных "выполнено"

Comment: @Mike, да, ошибки действительно очень странно выглядят. Подождем что скажет автор вопроса...

Comment: Например "Строки сценария: 3-31" - клиент выпоняет блок как скрипт и сообщает, где он находит следующий запрос для выполнения, т.е он не настроен под работу с ораклом. Или ещё возможно, но мало вероятно, что он пропарсил блок и не обнаружил  / из-за специалэных символов и т.п.. @Mike прав, в `sqlplus` всё будет работать.